# Overriding java methods with the same name

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, overriding

I am new to java and currently taking up a training but still can't cope with some topics especially inheritance.

I am currently working on a simple program to try, is it possible to override an abstract method with the same name but different variables inside the inheritance class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post a [mcve] showing us what you have done, and what you are trying to do.  Otherwise, your question will be downvoted, and/or closed, and you'll receive useless, helpful answers like "no, it is not possible."

Comment: Do you mean parameters or local variables? Different in what way?

Comment: local variables because this is an abstract method. Different in a way that the first overridden method displays a line of statement only and the second one will label and display attributes values from another class.

Comment: Show us code.  A stripped down version of your base class, showing 1 abstract method, and a stripped down version of your derived class, showing the method as you are trying to override it and/or the method as you are trying to overload it.  Code will make it clear what you mean better than vague statements.  Also, don't comment to add clarifications to your question; **edit** your question adding the clarifying details.

Answer (score 0):

When you said "different variables inside" I took the liberty of assuming you might mean the method parameters, thus overloading an inherited method.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    abstract void aMethod(int a);
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    void aMethod(int a){
        // Some code here, this is the normal thing to do when overriding
    }

    void aMethod(String b){
        // Some code here, this is okay too, but doesn't work with polymorphism
    }
}
```

The 2nd method can never be called on an instance of the `Parent` class, and can only be called by a instance of the `Child` class.

PS: I haven't got my Java IDE close right now so I haven't been able to check if it compiles, but I researched around before posting. [Here's another question](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-overload-an-abstract-method-in-Java) about overriding and overloading an abstract method. See the third answer there.